zsh variable expansion
I'm a bit of a noob with *nix and sh vs bash vs zsh specifically. Can someone explain this syntax with shell variables? What syntax do I need to use to get a filename pattern held in a variable to correctly pass to a command? Thanks!
#!/bin/zsh
f=tes?.sh
ls $f

Results in:
% ./test.sh
ls: tes?.sh: No such file or directory

But if I use #!/bin/sh or #!/bin/bash it works as expected:
% sh ./test.sh
test.sh

